# Problem with keras.Dense. The last dimension of the inputs to a Dense layer should be defined. Found None. Full input shape received: (None, None)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, training-data, keras-layer, siamese-network

I wrote some python code to develop a siamese network. The sub-clase from keras.Model is:

class modelSIAMESE(keras.Model):
def **init**(self):
super().**init**()
input_shape = target_shape + (3,)
input_a = Input(shape = input_shape)
input_b = Input(shape = input_shape)
input_activation = 'relu'
hidden_activation = 'relu'
output_activation = 'sigmoid'
self.conv1 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation=input_activation, input_shape=input_shape)
self.pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))
self.conv2 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation=hidden_activation)
self.pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))
self.conv3 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation=hidden_activation)
self.pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))
self.flatten = Flatten()
self.dense1 = Dense(128, activation="relu", input_shape=(None,))
# Procesar las imágenes de entrada a través de las capas compartidas
self.norm_a = layers.BatchNormalization() #(self.flatten(self.pool3(self.conv3(self.pool2(self.conv2(self.pool1(self.conv1(input_a))))))))
self.norm_b = layers.BatchNormalization() #(self.flatten(self.pool3(self.conv3(self.pool2(self.conv2(self.pool1(self.conv1(input_b))))))))
# Definir la capa de comparación
self.distance = keras.layers.Subtract()
self.prediction = Dense(units=1, activation=output_activation, input_shape=(None,None))
self.dropout = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)
def call(self, inputs, training=False):
input_a = inputs["input_a"]
input_b = inputs["input_b"]
x = self.conv1(input_a)
y = self.conv1(input_b)
x = self.pool1(x)
y = self.pool1(y)
x = self.conv2(x)
y = self.conv2(y)
x = self.pool2(x)
y = self.pool2(y)
x = self.conv3(x)
y = self.conv3(y)
x = self.pool3(x)
y = self.pool3(y)
x = self.dense1(x)
y = self.dense1(y)
x = self.norm_a(x)
y = self.norm_b(y)
x = self.flatten(x)
y = self.flatten(y)
d = self.distance([x, y]) #
d = K.abs(d)
d = self.dropout(d, training=training)
return self.prediction(d)

But, when is running the compile and training methods, I received a exception error similar with my title, where the focused line is "return self.prediction(d)". I would be very grateful if someone could tell me where the error is and what code I should modify.

I have tried different ways and still can't solve it.

Comment: Please format the code properly.